# Second monitor causes signal flip on and off after reboot

Tags: multiple-monitors

If I connect a second monitor to computer's GPU while Ubuntu is running everything works fine.
But if I boot with the second monitor connected to the GPU, signals starts to go constantly switching on and off on both of my monitors making the image come on and go off fast.

First monitor is connected via displayport cable.
Second monitor is connected via hdmi-dvi cable.

Also tested with another second monitor, this time using a regular hdmi cable and same result.

All tested monitor got their power from wall sockets.

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

GPU: Radeon RX 7700 XT

```
CPU: 8-core AMD Ryzen 7 7700X (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max: 1023/400/5573 MHz
Kernel: 6.5.0-25-generic x86_64 Up: 7m Mem: 3581.1/31224.8 MiB (11.5%)
Graphics:
Device-1: AMD driver: amdgpu v: kernel
Device-2: AMD driver: amdgpu v: kernel
Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
  compositor: gnome-shell driver: gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1: 2560x1440~144Hz
  2: 1280x1024~60Hz
OpenGL: renderer: GFX1101 (gfx1101 LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.54 6.5.0-25-generic)
  v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
```

Comment: Sounds like having both monitors drawing startup power at the same time is causing an undervoltage to both monitors.  Can you supply external power to one of them?

Comment: @waltinator both monitors get their power straight from wall outlets. Also the signal on and off switching is not only once, but constant on seemingly random intervals, maybe more if I’m playing a video. I’ll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Ubuntu from 22.04.4 LTS to 23.10 solved the problem.